# Does a Umbraco custom DataEditor know it's pagetype?

Tags: c#, plugins, umbraco

Question in the title. I am thinking of the posibility of making a DataEditor for dictionary items hosted on the current template. To make it as easy as possible to translate the page's text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of ascertaining the doc type of the node that your Custom Data Editor is on is to simply look it up using the Document API.

```
var nodeId = int.Parse(Request["id"]);
var umbracoDocument = new Document(nodeId);
```

Now you have the Document class you can work out the document type or interact with it in all sorts of ways. For example to get the Document Type alias:

```
var documentTypeAlias = d.ContentType.Alias;
```

There are various discussions on this approach and others here:

- http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/7452-Document-type-alias-in-custom-datatype
- [http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst8994_Get-Parent-Nodes-in-Custom-DataType.aspx](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/7452-Document-type-alias-in-custom-datatype)